# Loopback 4 Command line script: The key 'repositories.CurrencyRepository' is not bound to any value in context

Tags: loopback4

Using Loopback 4, I am trying to execute a simple get request after which I want to store some data in my database.

I would like to execute the following code from the command line:

```
import {WebshopApplication} from '../application';
import axios from 'axios';
import {CurrencyRepository} from '../repositories';

export async function importCurrencies(args: string[]) {

  const app = new WebshopApplication();
  await app.boot();


  const host = 'http://data.fixer.io/api';
  const accessToken = 'access_key=mykey';

  const currencyRepository = await app.getRepository(CurrencyRepository);
  const currencies = currencyRepository.find({});
  console.log(currencies);

  try {

    const resp = await axios.get(`${host}/latest?${accessToken}` );
    const currencies = resp.data;
    console.log(currencies);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  process.exit(0);
}

importCurrencies(process.argv).catch(err => {
  console.error('Cannot import currencies due to error', err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

When i execute:

```
 ts-node src/commands/import-currency.command.ts
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot import currencies due to error Error: The key 'repositories.CurrencyRepository' is not bound to any value in context WebshopApplication-f9b12a86-ec04-46b4-8e87-4031a4ab71f9
```

Why is this not working?

**UPDATE 26-05-2020:**

I have updated the above script to the following as per a suggestion in the commands.

```
import {WebshopApplication} from '../application';
import axios from 'axios';
import {CurrencyRepository} from '../repositories';
import {bind, BindingScope} from '@loopback/context';

@bind({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
export class ImportCurrencies {

  generate = async () => {
    const app = new WebshopApplication();
    await app.boot();

    const host = 'http://data.fixer.io/api';
    const accessToken ='mytoken';

    const currencyRepository = await app.getRepository(CurrencyRepository);
    const currencies = currencyRepository.find({});

    const resp = await axios.get(`${host}/latest?${accessToken}`);
    const currencies = resp.data;

    process.exit(0);
  }
}

const importCurrencies = new ImportCurrencies();

importCurrencies.generate().catch(err => {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Unfortunately adding the binding at the top of the class did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoopBack 4 has the concept of Booters to dynamically link certain assets (such as Repositories) during runtime. Booters look for *built, JavaScript files* in the `/dist` folder.

As such, the application must be built using `npm run build` and then the application must be run in its completely-built form:

```
    node dist/command/import-currency.command.js
```

Answer (score 2):

is basically indicating that a binding key wasn't bound properly to the application context. Do you have 'repositories.CurrencyRepository' bound in SINGLETON scope? full explanation here  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/docs/site/Dependency-injection.md#dependency-injection-for-bindings-with-different-scopes

it suggest to do this:

```
@bind({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
export class someDatasource extends juggler.DataSource {
}
```

Or

> The issue seems to be coming from the @loopback/context. As a temp
>   workaround, use "@loopback/context": "1.5.1" instead of the latest.

RaymondFeng told that it was a binding scope issue in Loopback 4 see : 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/2513

Dependency injection for bindings with different scopes:
Contexts can form a chain and bindings can be registered at different levels. The binding scope controls not only how bound values are cached, but also how its dependencies are resolved.

possible Troubleshooting:

`import {CurrencyRepository} from '../repositories';` 
-->is the path correct? ../?

Comment: I have tried to add the bind decorator, but unfortunately that did not work either. The same error remains

Comment: Also, downgrading to 1.5.1 seems to be quite far back from the current 3.8.1. That comment was made in feb 2019, more then a year ago from today. The path to the repository is correct. I have a src/commands folder and a src/repositories folder in my structure,